# latest chrome, firefox browsers are not working with selenium 3.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using firefox 48 and chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) with selenium webdriver 3.0. Used geckodriver for firefox also.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "D:\\Software\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();//for firefox 

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//for chrome
```

I am getting following error:

1. `Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055` (in case of
   firefox)
2. `Null pointer exception` (in case of chrome)

Comment: have a look for firefox.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium

Comment: And for chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864495/chrome-browser-not-getting-invoked-through-selenium/38864831#38864831

Comment: @Saurabh, thanks for kind reply. But I have doubt regarding below:    "export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/of/executable/downloaded/in/previous/step". What should I update in system path ?

Comment: In which OS current you are working??

Comment: Sir I am using Windows 10

Comment: Then that command works in Unix system, in your case no need to execute that command,You should update downloaded executeable `geckodriver.exe` and `chromedriver.exe` in your system path.. but you are already setting in your code as `Syetem.setProperty`.. so no need..:)

Comment: Sir what should I do now as any latest browser is not working with selenium 3.0 ? I have tested with MS Edge browser also. Please suggest

Comment: Just downgrade your selenium version to `Selenium-2.53.1`..Because you are using beta version of selenium now which is not stable until final version will not be released..:)

Comment: Selenium 2.53.1 is working with firefox 46.0.1 and latest chrome browser, but its not working with MS Edge. I am using MS Edge 25.105. Please suggest me are both compatible. I am getting following error when: The server did not provide any stacktrace information

Comment: Follow this url..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865751/selenium-with-microsoft-edge-driver-never-finishes-initialising/37946776#37946776